# Convert array string to array for mapping data

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, string, react-native

Here is my problem

```
const data = "[\"https://i.imgur.com/PAYXC2n.jpg\",\"https://i.imgur.com/bEfjjxA.jpg\"]";
```

I want to convert this string to array,
expected result will be :

```
res =["https://i.imgur.com/PAYXC2n.jpg","https://i.imgur.com/bEfjjxA.jpg"]
```

I use it for mapping data in React JS project, so i need to convert this string to array.

Comment: @JuanMendes they did, but they forgot to format their code.

Answer (score 2):

Just parse it from JSON:

```js
const
  data = "[\"https://i.imgur.com/PAYXC2n.jpg\",\"https://i.imgur.com/bEfjjxA.jpg\"]",
  parsed = JSON.parse(data);

console.log(parsed);
```

Answer (score 2):

Do it:
`const dataArr = JSON.parse(data);`. This will parse as to object, which is your array (With out "")